# When using service account impersonation, when calling export on Google Docs using v3 API, viewedByMeTime timestamp is updated

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using a service account to access google doc files of users in my enterprise google account using impersonation.

See:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing

So far so good.

Then, I need to download contents of Google Docs.

When calling Google Drive API to download the contents of a Google Doc, the documentation says to run the following:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Here is a java program that should reproduce the problem:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FetchGoogleDocContentsWithServiceAccount {
  static int readTimeout = 60000;
  static int connectTimeout = 60000;
  static String serviceAccountId = "";
  static String serviceAccountEmail = "";
  static String serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile = "";
  static String serviceAccountPrivateKeyFilePassword = "";
  static String fileId = "";
  static JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  static NetHttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  static List<String> googleScopeList = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Drive drive = (new Drive.Builder(httpTransport,
        jacksonFactory,
        getRequestInitializer(getGoogleCredentials())))
        .setApplicationName("Sample app").build();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    drive.files().export(fileId, "application/vnd.google-apps.document")
        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(baos);

    System.out.println(baos.toString("UTF-8"));
  }

  public static HttpRequestInitializer getRequestInitializer(final GoogleCredential requestInitializer) {
    return httpRequest -> {
      requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
      httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(readTimeout);
      httpRequest.setReadTimeout(connectTimeout);
    };
  }

  public static GoogleCredential getGoogleCredentials() {
    GoogleCredential credential;

    try {
      GoogleCredential.Builder b = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
          .setJsonFactory(jacksonFactory).setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
          .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(),
              new FileInputStream(new File(serviceAccountPrivateKeyFile)), serviceAccountPrivateKeyFilePassword,
              "privatekey", serviceAccountPrivateKeyFilePassword))
          .setServiceAccountScopes(googleScopeList);
      if (serviceAccountEmail != null) {
        b = b.setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountEmail);
      }
      credential = b.build();
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e1) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not build client secrets", e1);
    }
    return credential;
  }
}
```

When I have performed this operation, we are seeing that the `viewedByMeTime` field is actually being updated as the impersonated user.

This is not good, because now people think someone might have stolen access to their account. They are going to open tickets with the security team.

Is this expected? How can I make this stop? Is there another method in the API I can call to download the google docs without updating this timestamp?

Also opened a ticket on the github for the google drive java sdk: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/issues/3160

Comment: In my environment, even when the Google Docs file is exported by the service account, `viewedByMeTime` was not changed. So although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, if `viewedByMeTime` is changed and you don't want to change it, for example, how about modifying `viewedByMeTime` using Files: update method of Drive API? When Files: update method is used, `viewedByMeTime` can be changed. Is this useful for your situation? But if I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: are you sure it's a Google Doc? not a normal file? Please share the code snippet you used. and no, i cannot make any updates.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. At first, can I ask you about whether my understanding is correct? About your question, I tested for Google Docs with https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update At that time, I changed the access token to that of the service account. I could confirm `viewedByMeTime` could be modified. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DaImTo i already included the only relevant java code.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza sorry thats not enough for met to test with.  YOu need to supply a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  for example where is the code you are using for authorization, which scopes are you using.  There could be any number of issues with this that we cant see with one line of code.

Comment: ok i'll work on this.

Comment: @DaImTo I added the example as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `viewedByMeTime` field upon calling the endpoint **is** indeed intended behaviour. Any action performed through the API is considered the same way as if the user did that action manually (i.e. that field would be updated too when the user visits the document through the UI).

By using domain-wise delegation (or "user impersonation"), you have no way to avoid this issue.

The only workaround would be to give the service account access to this file, and let it export the file without domain-wide delegation. The `viewedByMeTime` field will be updated only for the service account itself, but not for the original owner of that file (or any other user having access to it).

Comment: If that is the intended behavior... then it is inconsistent with the download operation on non-google doc files from google drive. I've reported it as an issue that needs addressed.